# Something is periodically repairing my Office installation - how can I find out what it is?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office, driver

I have 32-bit Office 2010 installed, and for development reasons I need both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Access Database Driver. You need to trick Windows into accepting this set-up (see here: http://techblog.aimms.com/2014/10/27/installing-32-bit-and-64-bit-microsoft-access-drivers-next-to-each-other/)

The above method requires me to delete the mso.dll value from the regkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths. However, something is periodically restoring that key, confusing my system as to which driver to use and 'breaking' the 64-bit version of our product.

Does anyone know how I might discover what is occasionally 'repairing' my Office install? Can I set something up to 'watch' a reg key and record what changes it?
Any ideas?

Comment: One has to assume that there is *some* reason why the default behaviour of the Access Database Engine installer prevents both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions from being installed on the same machine, forcing you to "trick Windows" into letting it happen. You now have an unsupported configuration so *"Don't do that."* may turn out to be the best answer you get.

Comment: That might be the case, but it's not really an adequate solution on Microsoft's part. It essentially means you're "not allowed" to develop a 64-bit product that interfaces with Access databases unless you also use 64-bit Office, which no-one does....