# Reading MDB files from 64bit Python on a machine with 32bit MS Office

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, adodbapi

I want to read the contents of a series of MS Access databases from a 64bit Python application under Windows.

The machine on which I want to do this has 32bit versions of various MS Office applications installed (but not Access). This prevents my loading the 64bit versions of the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

That would seem to prevent me using pyodbc or adodbapi to access the files, as they would appear to need the 64bit database driver installed.

At the moment I have sidestepped this by reading the MDB files into a Postgresql database using a 32bit application, and then accessing the Postgresql data from the 64bit Python application.

Any ideas for something more direct?

Comment: Can you give this a try, and if it works, I'll make it an answer? I know going in the other direction you can use the `/passive` option during the install of the Access driver (32 bit driver on 64 bit Office). I'm not sure if it works the other way. Download here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 Then try installing from the command line as an administrator with something like `C:\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive`? Let me know if it works!

Comment: ( cc: @FlipperPA ) - Be advised that there have been many reports of `/passive` installs breaking things and causing weirdness (e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35858119/2144390)).

Comment: I think the suggestion from @FkipperPA to use /passive install of the drivers is too risky. I've sidestepped this issue for my proof-of-concept prototype. If I take this further I'll probably to part of the job using 32 bit python.